# LDAP login returns Invalid Username/Password when Flask application is deployed via Apache

Tags: apache, python-2.7, flask, flask-login, ldap3

LDAP login works when my Flask App is launched (locally), however, using the same code and server, when deploying the app via Apache, LDAP returns 'Invalid Username/Password'.

The following are the only logs I could find:

```
DEBUG:root:Validating LDAPLoginForm against LDAPDEBUG:flask_ldap3_login:Opening connection with bind user 'ldapuser@example.com'
DEBUG:flask_ldap3_login:Destroying connection at <0x7f6af0d29950>
ERROR:flask_ldap3_login:no active server available in server pool after maximum number of tries
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Is the server you're running on, on the same local network as your Dev machine, or did you mean that your Apache installation is actually on the same machine as you're developing on?

Comment: I ran the Flask development server on the same machine as the actual Apache installation for testing purposes, and LDAP authentication works via the Flask Server, therefore the problem must be from the Apache configuration.